# Octave 4.0 Command Window text not visible in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, do-release-upgrade, octave

After using do-release-upgrade (from 12.04 to 14.04 to 16.04) the Octave Command Window does not show text typed into it. However, commands entered there do indeed appear in the Command History window. This happens on two different computers. On the other hand, when I installed 16.04 from scratch (from DVD) on another computer, the problem did not occur. Possibly something amiss in the do-release-upgrade procedure. Note: Installing octave-strings as mentioned in another post did not help in my case. I'm at Ubuntu 16.04.2.

Comment: Incidentally, I tried purging and then installing octave, but to no avail.  Also, the edit window works fine.

Comment: Does the text become visible (inverted) if you select (double click) on it? is it perhaps a color / theming issue?

Comment: No, text does not become visible. The cursor does not even move when I type something. When I double click at any point in the command window, the entire line at that point turns black. However, when I type a command (which is invisible) and hit Enter, the command appears in the Command History. If the command is "plot" with an appropriate argument, then a plot does appear, so apparently the commands are being recognized.

Comment: I've been trying octave on-and-off for the last couple hours, and after starting it up about 10 times or so, it actually worked once, but then it didn't work the next time.  Correct operation seems to be intermittent. I also get this message occasionally: " panic: Segmentation fault -- stopping myself..." and sometimes: "attempting to save variables to 'octave-workspace'..." "octave exited with signal 11".

Answer (score 1):

I was getting similar symptoms with the exception of the segfault or command window occasionally working.  I am remotely connecting to the Ubuntu 16.04.2 box via TigerVNC.  What resolved the issue for me was setting the following environment variables:

export GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge:unity-gtk-module 
export GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-depricated

More details can be found on Octave's bug repository: http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?44174